# leanModal close and open other window function

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a website that has two links at the top of the page, "Login | Register". when either is clicked they open a leanModal window. All of that is working fine, the issue i have is in the register window, there is a link that has the option to sign in, when the user clicks on that link, theoretically, the register window should close and the login window should open, unfortunately this is not the case as both windows stay open. I would like to know how to close and open the different modal windows with one click, if possible.

**sample code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({ top : 200, overlay: 0.8, closeButton:   ".modal_close" });       
        });
</script>






  **nav**
  <div id="reg">
  <a rel="leanModal" href="#signup">LOGIN</a>|
  <a rel="leanModal" href="#register">REGISTER</a>     </div>
  **nav end**




**register**
    <div id="register" align="left" >
    <div id="register-header">

            <h2>REGISTER NEW ACCOUNT</h2>
            <a class="modal_close" href="#"></a>
            </div>

<div id="register-ct">
<form action="register-action.cfm" method="post" id="register-new">
<div class="txt-fld">
                <label for="">User Full Name</label>
              <input id=""  name="user_full_name" type="text" class="required"/>
              </div>
              <div class="txt-fld">
                <label for="">Username</label>
                <input id=""  name="user_name" type="text" class="required"/>

              </div>
              <div class="txt-fld">
                <label for="">EMAIL ADDRESS</label>
                <input id="" name="user_email" type="email" class="required"/>
              </div>
              <div class="txt-fld">
                <label for="">PASSWORD</label>
            <input id="" name="user_password" type="password"  class="required"/>

              </div>
              <div class="btn-fld" align="center">
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
    </div>
</form>
    </div>


    <p class="pmod">Already a member? <a rel="leanModal" href="#signup">SIGN IN</a></p>
    </div>
```

**login**

```
  <div id="signup">
        <div id="signup-ct">
            <div id="signup-header">
                <h2>USER LOGIN</h2>
                <a class="modal_close" href="#"></a>
            </div>

            <form action="login-action.cfm" method="post">

              <cfoutput>
              <input name="url" type="hidden" value="#currentURL#" />
              </cfoutput>
              <div class="txt-fld">
                <label for="">EMAIL ADDRESS</label>
                <input id="" name="user_email" type="text" />
              </div>
              <div class="txt-fld">
                <label for="">PASSWORD</label>
                <input id="" name="user_password" type="password" />

              </div>
              <div class="btn-fld">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
            </div>
             </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would like this link:

```
**<p class="pmod">Already a member? <a rel="leanModal" href="#signup">SIGN IN</a></p>**
```

to have to function to close the register window and immediately open the login window.

Thanks in advance.

John

Answer (score 0):

The goal is : close the current modal when you'll click you "Login" in your register window, then open the Login modal.

First you need to edit your js.

1/ Add the link in register window :

```
<p class='signup-link'>
   You already have an account? <a rel="leanModal" name="login" href="#login">Log In</a>
</p>
```

2/ Edit your js
Add an option to defaults :

```
var defaults={top:100,overlay:0.5,closeButton:null,signuplink:".signup-link"};
```

The new option is "signuplink" and you put the name of the previous class for your link

3/ Then Add a new function :

```
function close_modal_id(modal_id){$(modal_id).css({"display":"none"})}}})})(jQuery);
```

This function will close ONLY your modal, and not your #lean_overlay

4/ Your this function to close your register window

```
$(o.signuplink).click(function(){close_modal_id("#signup")});
```

5/ Add the new option on your html if you want to change it

```
$('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({ top : 200, overlay:0.85, closeButton: ".btn-close", signuplink:".signup-link" });
```

That's all!

So :

In your html page, you'll have that in your head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({ top : 200, overlay:0.85, closeButton: ".btn-close", signuplink:".signup-link" });        
        });
</script>
```

Then this link in your register window :

```
<p class='signup-link'>
   You already have an account? <a rel="leanModal" name="login" href="#login">Log In</a>
</p>
```

And finally this js code edited :

```
// leanModal v1.1 by Ray Stone - http://finelysliced.com.au
// Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL

(function ($) {$.fn.extend({leanModal: function (options) {var defaults = { top: 100, overlay: 0.5, closeButton: null, signuplink: ".signup-link" };var overlay = $("<div id='lean_overlay'></div>");$("body").append(overlay);options = $.extend(defaults, options);return this.each(function () {var o = options;$(this).click(function (e) {var modal_id = $(this).attr("href");$("#lean_overlay").click(function () { close_modal(modal_id) });$(o.closeButton).click(function () { close_modal(modal_id) });$(o.signuplink).click(function () { close_modal_id("#signup") });var modal_height = $(modal_id).outerHeight();var modal_width = $(modal_id).outerWidth();$("#lean_overlay").css({ "display": "block", opacity: 0 });$("#lean_overlay").fadeTo(200, o.overlay);$(modal_id).css({ "display": "block", "position": "fixed", "opacity": 0, "z-index": 11000, "left": 50 + "%", "margin-left": -(modal_width / 2) + "px", "top": o.top + "px" });$(modal_id).fadeTo(200, 1); e.preventDefault()})});function close_modal(modal_id) { $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200); $(modal_id).css({ "display": "none" }) };function close_modal_id(modal_id) { $(modal_id).css({ "display": "none" }) }}})})(jQuery);
```